# How to register new template for cordova / phonegap?

Tags: cordova, templates

Is it possible to have the phonegap/cordova CLI list a complete template developed in-house?

If this information is readily available online I apologize up front, but I can't seem to find it anywhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm out of luck, it seems.

The template names are listed in the installed `package.json` file that belong to the Phonegap/Cordova installation.

In my example (Ubuntu) it's located in: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/package.json`.

It would seem I will have to make my own Git-driven templating mechanism.